# cbind columns of varying length, filtering observations that do not share a common index in R

Tags: r

I have 6 time series objects stored in their own dataframe, each with an index from 2000-01-01 to 2010-01-01, however, the observations differ for each object. For clarification, whilst each object might have an observation for 2005-01-01, one object might not have an observation for 2010-02-01, whilst all 5 others do.

I want to use cbind to bind them all together, however, as each object has a differing length I can't (and the fact I want to find the time-varying correlations between each object). Basically I want to find a way to only bind 'complete cases' across all 6 objects, and slot them into their respective index spot.

I am thinking of creating a data frame with a time index ranging from 2000-01-01 to 2010-01-01, binding them to their respective time index (this is the part I don't know how to do), and then using complete cases to remove the observations that don't share a common index. If there is a better way to do this, clarification is also appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be:

### 1

Create a data frame with the full time range from `2000-01-01` to `2010-01-01`. For this you can use `seq()`.

### 2

Use `dplyr::left_join()` to join your various data frames onto this reference data frame (make sure to give your reference data frame as the first argument of `left_join()`).

**Edit to explain comment:**

`left_join` needs to "know", how to join the data frames together. You have two options:

- you can give the same name for your reference data frame's date column (so, for instance, if your 6 data frames's date variable is called "Date", your reference data frame's only column should also be called "Date")
- or, if you called it something else (say, "Reference" for instance), you need to add a `by` argument: `left_join(df_ref, df1, by = c("Reference", "Date"))`

Comment: I like this, but for some reason they won't join. I keep getting the following error:
> left_join(df1, df2)
Error: `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables

Answer (score 0):

You could go for a `full_join` from `dplyr`. I'd suggest to load `tidyverse`, just in case the task gets more complex (see the examples below).

Example dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(time = c("2012-01-01"), var_A = c(3))
df2 <- data.frame(time = c("2010-01-01", "2012-01-01"), var_B = c(3, 2))
df3 <- data.frame(time = c("2011-01-01", "2012-01-01"), var_C = c(0, 0))
```

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df1 %>%
  full_join(df2, by = "time") %>%
  full_join(df3, by = "time")
```

Output:

```
df

        time var_A var_B var_C
1 2012-01-01     3     2     0
2 2010-01-01    NA     3    NA
3 2011-01-01    NA    NA     0
```

This can also be shortened:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- list(df1, df2, df3) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = "time")
```

Output:

```
        time var_A var_B var_C
1 2012-01-01     3     2     0
2 2010-01-01    NA     3    NA
3 2011-01-01    NA    NA     0
```

If you need it arranged, you can then always use `arrange` afterwards.

P.S. If you're missing some of the dates in that sequence in your dataframes, you can just add few lines to the statement to complement them (I've also added a `replace` statement to fill NAs with 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

list(df1, df2, df3) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = "time") %>%
  mutate(time = as.Date(time)) %>%
  complete(time = seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2010-01-01"), by="month")) %>%
  replace(., is.na(.), 0)
```

In the above case I've added a sequence from `2000-01-01` until `2010-01-01` by month, but you can also change that to `min(time)` and `max(time)` or what would suit you best.

Comment: I don't think that this answers the OP's question because not all of their data frames have data for all the dates. I think that you need to first create a data frame with all the dates and then I think that `left_join` is what is needed here (see my answer).

Comment: @prosoitos, that's up to the OP to juge. However, in case the OP would indeed need to complement the dataset, I've added additional lines that can handle that easily.

Answer (score 0):

In Base R you could do

```
merge( merge( df1, df2, all = TRUE ), df3, all = TRUE )
```

which gives you

```
        time var_A var_B var_C
1 2012-01-01     3     2     0
2 2010-01-01    NA     3    NA
3 2011-01-01    NA    NA     0
```